# Append other displayed dimensions and weight units in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, dimensions

can someone share function code to have another unit beside current unit for weight and dimension in Woocommerce?

Example like image bellow

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2**  *(March 2019)*

The following code will append to default displayed dimensions and weight additional converted units values, as desired:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_weight', 'custom_format_weight', 20, 2 );
function custom_format_weight( $weight_string, $weight ){
    // Format decimals from default weight value
    $weight_string  = wc_format_localized_decimal( $weight );
    // Format decimals from custom converted weight value
    $weight_string2 = wc_format_localized_decimal( round($weight * 0.45359237, 2) );

    if ( ! empty( $weight_string ) ) {
        $weight_string2 = ' ( ' . $weight_string2 . ' ' . __( 'kg', 'woocommerce' ) . ' )';
        $weight_string .= ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) . $weight_string2;
    } else {
        $weight_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $weight_string;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_dimensions', 'custom_format_dimensions', 10, 2 );
function custom_format_dimensions( $dimension_string, $dimensions ){
    // Initializing variable
    $dimentions2 = array();

    // Loop though dimensions array (and set custom converted formatted decimals values in a new array)
    foreach( $dimensions as $key => $value ){
        if( ! empty($value) && $value != 0 )
            $dimentions2[$key] = wc_format_localized_decimal( round($value * 2.54, 2) );
    }

    // Format default dimentions in a string
    $dimension_string  = implode( ' x ', array_filter( array_map( 'wc_format_localized_decimal', $dimensions ) ) );

    if ( ! empty( $dimension_string ) ) {
        // Format custom converted array in a string and append it to default formatted dimensions string
        $dimension_string2 = ' ( ' . implode( ' x ', $dimentions2 ) . ' ' . __( 'cm', 'woocommerce' ) . ' )';
        $dimension_string .= ' ' . get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ) . $dimension_string2;
    } else {
        $dimension_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $dimension_string;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

Comment: It's work but not change the calculation for another unit yet. WEIGHT 6.61 lbs (6.61 kg), DIMENSIONS 112.21 x 7.87 x 14.88 in (112.21 x 7.87 x 14.88 cm)

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec , I have a question regarding this answer, what if we don't have a height? in main dimension it is none but when it changes to next dimension it is a 0, like : (2.3 x 21.3 x 0)

Comment: @BabakHabibi Yes you are right, thanks, I have updated the code…  Now if one of the dimensions fields is empty, it will do the same way than in default woocommerce (not displaying it, so if height is empty, it will display (2.3 x 21.3) …

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to show product weigth with comma. Let's say 1,2kg.
Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_weight', 'custom_format_weight', 20, 2 );
function custom_format_weight( $weight_string, $weight ){
    // Format decimals from default weight value
    $weight_string  = wc_format_localized_decimal( $weight );
    // Format decimals from custom converted weight value
    $x = floor($weight_string);
    $y = $weight_string - floor($weight_string);
    $y = str_replace("0.", "", $y);

    $kila = $x.", ".$y." kg";

    if ( ! empty( $weight_string ) ) {
        $weight_string = $kila;
    } else  {
        $weight_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $weight_string;
}
```